# Como extrair um valor de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Sou iniciante em Python e tenho que calcular as 4 notas de 10 alunos e guardar cada média em uma lista, só que tenho que mostrar quantos alunos ficaram com média 7 ou maior que 7, mais não estou encontrando um jeito de extrair esses valores da lista (média) que é onde esta guardada as médias dos 10 alunos. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
media = list()
for vezes in range(1,11):
    print(f'{vezes} Aluno')
    if vezes <= 10 :
        n_1 = float(input('Digite 1° nota: '))
        n_2 = float(input('Digite 2° nota: '))
        n_3 = float(input('Digite 3° nota: '))
        n_4 = float(input('Digite 4° nota: '))
        alunos = (n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4) / 4
        media.append(alunos)
    else:
        print('ERROR 404!#@@')
    print(media)
```

Answer (score -1):

Então para calcular o total de todos alunos quer ficaram com a media 7 basta você criar uma variavel que ira receber 0, e no for você ira colocar um if aluno >= 7: e ira adicionar o nome da variavel += 1

```
media = list()
cont = 0
for vezes in range(1,11):
    print(f'{vezes} Aluno')
    if vezes <= 10 :
        n_1 = float(input('Digite 1° nota: '))
        n_2 = float(input('Digite 2° nota: '))
        n_3 = float(input('Digite 3° nota: '))
        n_4 = float(input('Digite 4° nota: '))
        alunos = (n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4) / 4
        media.append(alunos)
    
    else:
        print('ERROR 404!#@@')
    print(media)

    if alunos >= 7:
        cont += 1

print(f"O total de alunos com a media 7 foi {cont}")
```